# Current value in Range validator ErrorMessage - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This may be something really simply, but I just can't find any examples that do what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to display the current value in my rangeattribute validator for my model.

I'm trying to decorating my property like so...

```
<Required>
<Display(Name:="Invoice(s) Amount")>
<Range(1, Decimal.MaxValue, ErrorMessage:="The value '{don't know what goes here}' is not valid for {0}.")>
<DataType(DataType.Currency)>
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=False, DataFormatString:="{0:C2}")>
Public Property InvoiceAmount As Decimal
```

I've seen lots of examples where {1} and {2} are used to display the min and max for the range. However I haven't seen anything where the current value is displayed.

If I enter some non-numeric value, it displays the default messages as...

```
The value 'asdf' is not valid for Invoice(s) Amount.
```

This is why I'm assuming there aught to be some way to do it also for the range.

So essentially what I want to do is display the same kind of message when the value is a valid decimal, but is outside the allowed range, so it could be something like...

```
The value '-100' is not valid for Invoice(s) Amount.
```

It seems like it should be really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with RangeAttribute, but create a class inherited form RangeAttribute and you can override the default behaviour and do what you like.